# Invalid characters error in http.js while parsing incoming email

Tags: node.js

Kind of reached deadlock.

I am setting up https://github.com/MLstate/PEPS. Outgoing mail works but for incoming mail, it throws below error:

```
[DEBUG] [6C0540C0-04F9-4B5C-A4D0-1A69FC67F234.1] [core] running data_post hook in smtpin plugin                                                                             |
[CRIT] [-] [core] TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters                                                                                                 |
[CRIT] [-] [core]     at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:733:13)                                                                                           |
[CRIT] [-] [core]     at new ClientRequest (http.js:1429:14)                                                                                                                |
[CRIT] [-] [core]     at Object.exports.request (http.js:1899:10)                                                                                                           |
[CRIT] [-] [core]     at Request.start (/usr/local/haraka/node_modules/request/index.js:603:30)                                                                             |
[CRIT] [-] [core]     at Request.write (/usr/local/haraka/node_modules/request/index.js:1226:28)                                                                            |
[CRIT] [-] [core]     at MessageStream.ondata (stream.js:51:26)                                                                                                             |
[CRIT] [-] [core]     at MessageStream.emit (events.js:95:17)                                                                                                               |
[CRIT] [-] [core]     at ChunkEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/Haraka/messagestream.js:352:18)                                                                    |
[CRIT] [-] [core]     at ChunkEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)                                                                                                                |
[CRIT] [-] [core]     at ChunkEmitter.end (/usr/lib/node_modules/Haraka/chunkemitter.js:92:14)                                                                              |
[NOTICE] [-] [core] Shutting down
```

Tried adding log lines in http.js file but for some reasons, it does not show up in the haraka.log.  Any clues on how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

- Most probable reason is that the client is not sending data in HTTP format. To validate that you can run 'curl -v -X TRACE [yourserver]' if you are in UNIX environment and catch what is incoming.
- Editing http.js does not help, as Node uses snapshot version of it's libraries, in-built into the executable. If you want to instrument Node libraries, follow this steps in [this site](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md)

Comment: Thanks for the tip but error is coming from haraka smtp server which I guess designed using node.  The error comes while trying to parse the incoming mail.

Comment: It may not be an error, instead in the correct format (SMTP protocol), while you are attempting to parse it through HTTP format. You may have to use 'net' module, as opposed to 'http' module, and parse the incoming message manually, for the right protocol.

Comment: Could be.  Its all part of https://github.com/MLstate/PEPS.  Not sure where to fiddle around. :(.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an invalid char, i.e. End line in your header. See below for more info.

http://www.alexkras.com/typeerror-the-header-content-contains-invalid-characters/

Comment: The info is good but dont know how to proceed forward or troubleshoot.